# Multiple Records with Same Number, Show One With Lowest Price

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I Have a Model

Model-1 having fields

- Number Price
- Price

Number can be same. I want to show All Model-1 record but if there is Two or More records with same number,I want it just show Record having Lowest Price.

For example if Results of Model-1.all is

- 86758 number - Price = 20
- 86758 number - Price = 50
- 23213 number - Price = 120
- 65656 number - Price = 30
- 65656 number - Price = 60

I want Where i have Multiple Records with Same Number, Show One With Lowest Price,LIKE

- 86758 number - Price = 20
- 23213 number - Price = 120
- 65656 number - Price = 30

How i will write a query in Controller.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your model name is Modal, then write query like :

`results = Modal.select('number, min(price) as min_price').group('number')`

Loop over results in view

```
  <%= results.each do |result| %>
    <%= result.number %>
    <%= result.min_price %>
  <%= end %>
```

Comment: how to access whole object, this is show a PART NUMBER

Comment: @SajjadMurtaza I didn't understood your comment .

Answer (score 1):

I would do a model scope where you can use that in your controller

It could go something like this

```
scope :number_with_lowest_price, -> {group(:number).having('price = min(price)')}
```

This way, you can use this on your model where ever you need to use it

```
Model1.number_with_lowest_price
```

This should render the results you would expect

Comment: this give me
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of HAVING must be type boolean, not type numeric

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to put in the matching statement. I edited the having portion in my answer. Try that out and let me know if that works. Thanks

Comment: .id must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: I would like to see the whole error message including the SQL statement that generated it if you don't mind

Comment: I called
Product.number_with_lowest_price

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "products.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" ...